how to create new folder in Ubuntu in 'files'
I have created new folders before in Ubuntu, in the 'files' utility, but that seems to be missing now.   I thought there was an icon for creating a new folder but there is none. If I try to right-click in the folder, the only options that show up in the menu are for that particular item that is selected in the folder I am looking at, and there doesn't seem to be a way to right-click in the folder without selecting something.   Did that icon for creating new folders get removed in the latest update?

place your mouse in a blank area of the files screen and right click mouse or use Shift + Ctrl + Nand it will introduce a new folder context menu

That worked.  Thanks

for completeness, I'll post that as answer https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

place your mouse in a blank area of the files screen and right click mouse or use Shift Ctrl + N with the window in focus and it will introduce a new folder context menu.

